# Where to put `export const dynamic` in Next Js 14.1.0?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm using nextjs 14.1.0. and getting this error from couple of days. After successfull production build visiting any *catch-all segments* route giving the 500 error on browser and 'Error: Page changed from static to dynamic at runtime /start
see more here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/app-static-to-dynamic-error' on console. As the documentation of the error suggests to add

```
export const dynamic = 'force-static'
```

or

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

My question is where should I add them. the documentation says to page. what does it mean?

- I am using *Catch-all Segments*  Do I have to add this to all the pages or just the *catch-all segments*?

Here is my project structure. If anything else regarding the question neede please let me know.

[image]

I've tried to add `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` to individual page route(s) and build each time.

Answer (score 1):

you can add 'force-static' or 'force-dynamic' config to all pages one by one. In case you want to add it to all pages at once: you may try creating a custom file inside pages directory and name it "_app.jsx" and then add the config into it like below.

`export const dynamic = 'force-static'; export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) { return <Component {...pageProps} /> }`

you can read more about [Custom App here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-app)